# Add parameters in tuple after initialisation in Swift

Tags: ios, tuples, swift

Is there any way to add parameters in tuple after initialisation?

Like :

```
var tupleX = ("Hi", "Rachit")
```

Now I want to add a parameter to tuple after which tupleX will have 3 or more parameters

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. A tuple has a set number of elements. You may want to use an Array or some other class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a tuple and a list (or other collections) is precisely the fixed amount of elements it contains.

From a type system perspective `(1, 2)` and `(1, 2, 3)` are of two distinct types, so of course you cannot alter the number of elements since you would be changing the type.

It's probably also important to notice that, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html),

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.

So if you need to alter a tuple overtime, you probably don't want to use a tuple, but rather a class, a struct or even a dictionary.

Comment: do not forget the keyword for tuples: those are _temporary_ stores only, not _persistent_ ones.

Comment: @holex I'm not sure what you mean by that. Is it a note about proper usage?

Comment: you said the only difference between tuples and collection is the fixed number of elements. however, the tuples are only temporary groups of related values rather than persistent data storing collections, so that compasiron with other collections may be misleading here, because the   tuples are temporary compounds only. that is which I did like to refer only, the difference is more significant.

Comment: @holex from a theoretical perspective the main differences with a list is the one I exposed. The way you use tuples comes straight from it. Anyway I can add a note.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella One clarification, a tuple in swift is not just defined by the amount of elements it contains, it is defined by the amount AND TYPE of the elements it contains.  `(Int, Int)` and `(Int, String)` are different, and non-interchangeable, types.

Comment: @David fair point, however, given a cardinality the generic-type is defined: `Tuple2<T1, T2>` is a valid generic type for any tuple with two elements.